# An Ito process with intermediate constraints

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have a controlled stochastic process described by

$\dot{x} = X(x) + u(t) + \eta_x(t),$

where $u$ is the control, $\eta_x$ is a white noise with zero mean. The equation is called Langevin equation. The initial value

$x(0) = x_0$

is given. It is also given that

$u(t) = A \sin(\omega t).$

The problem is to find the values of $A$ and $\omega$ which provide the constraints

$x(t_k) = x_k, ~~~ k = 1, ..., K,$

at the given instants $t_k$, $x_k$ are also given.

Let me fix $K = 2, t_1 = 1, x_1 = 0.5$ and $t_2 = 2, x_2 = 1$. What should the algorithm for finding $A$ and $\omega$ be look like?

Currently, I have this piece which works with fixed $A$ and $\omega$:

```
\[Rho]t = 1;
\[Delta]t = 9.062;
\[Gamma]t = 6.63 10^-3;
A = 1;
\[Omega] = 0.1;

sol = RandomFunction[
   ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[
        t] == \[DifferentialD]t*(\[Rho]t (1 - \[Gamma]t \
Sinh[\[Delta]t x[t]]) + A Sin[\[Omega] t]) + \[DifferentialD]\[Eta]x[
         t]}, x[t], {x, 0}, {t, 0}, \[Eta]x \[Distributed] 
     WienerProcess[]], {0, 1, 0.01}];
```

Now I have stucked on

1. how to involve a white noise with zero mean instead of the Wiener
   proc ([this](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-random-processes/generate-white-noise-based-on-any-distribution.html) somehow does not work)?
2. how to impose the intermediate constraints above?

Your help on either part is highly appreciated.

Comment: In which sense $x(t_k) = x_k$ if $x(t_k)$ is a random variable ?

Comment: I am not sure about the correct mathematics behind, but it  simply means that the trajectory of the particle must pass through some given points ($x_k$).

Comment: I think the `WhiteNoiseProcess` issue of the question may be a bug.  It seams that `WhiteNoiseProcess` only works in `RandomFunction` for integer time steps. `RandomFunction[
 WhiteNoiseProcess[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]], {0, 1, .1}]` fails but `RandomFunction[
 WhiteNoiseProcess[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]], {0, 10}]` succeeds.  Please report to WRI.

Comment: @Edmund You are right, that works! Thanks.
I was thinking about the intermediate constraints. What if I define two different processes with initial values at the constraints? Then the control $u$ will be a piecewise function and the problem will be to provide the terminal condition at each piece. Does it simplify the problem?